# Get Crittercism appId

Tags: android, crittercism

I created Crittercism account and followed [this](http://docs.crittercism.com/android/android.html) to integrate in my Android application but could not get the application Id.

Anybody please help me to get the application id from Crittercism account.

TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go to your App page, you will find it in Url

Example:

`https://app.crittercism.com/developers/crash-summary/527b160b8b2e3376d3000003`

App Id is `527b160b8b2e3376d3000003`

Comment: You can also view it in your app settings page, you'll see a link in the sidebar on the left side